# Tensorflow - ( retrain.py ) OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, virtualenv

I'm running tensorflow in Ubuntu (in VirtualEnv).

I want to create training model ...( using retrain.py to train the model )..

Github code link ==> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

I tried to use command to run in terminal

```
python image_retraining/retrain.py \

   --bottleneck_dir= /tf_files/bottlenecks \

   --how_many_training_steps 100 \

   --model_dir= /tf_files/inception \

   --output_graph= /tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \

   --output_labels= /tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \

   --image_dir = /Image_Processing/theory/Green
```

I'm getting error. How to read that error and how to resolve it..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1061, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/Image_Processing/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "image_retraining/retrain.py", line 777, in main
    maybe_download_and_extract()
  File "image_retraining/retrain.py", line 288, in maybe_download_and_extract
    os.makedirs(dest_directory)
  File "/Image_Processing/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Note :- I'm new in tensorflow and just started to use it..

Comment: It's trying to create the model directory and appears to fail. Can you  print `dest_directory` before `os.makedirs`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out .. dest_directory is empty string..

Comment: @THINK-TANK How did you specify the dest_directory?

Answer (score 1):

while running retrain.py, you do not have to specify all the parameters.
Just specify

```
python /path_to_file/retrain.py --img_dir /dir_containing_subfolders_of_images
```

while running the code and it will use default paths for remaining arguments. eg. /tmp/some_dir_or_file for most cases.

If you want to specify custom locations create the desired directories and specify those paths.
eg.

```
python /path_to_file/retrain.py 
--img_dir /dir_containing_subfolders_of_images
--how_many_training_steps number_of_steps
--output_graph /dirPath_to_store_output_graph/file_name.pb
--output_labels /dirPath_to_store_output_labels/file_name.txt
```