# Tensorflow Inception V3 unable to load compute graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I have retrained Tensorflow's Inception V3's last layer on a flower dataset. This was done using:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/flower_photos
```

The training was successful, and then I ran:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image
```

This too ran fine and next I ran:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

When I run this, I receive an error that says

```
E tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:285] Not found: Failed to load compute graph at '/tmp/output_graph.pb'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Make sure the file is existent.

Comment: sudo bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have run this using following command instead of bazel and I found it easier.

```
python /path_to_file/label_image.py /path_to_image/image.jpeg
```

First make sure that graph is created after you run retrain.py and it is at the correct location. (default is inside /tmp/). If you want you can get the script [here](https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_image_classifier/blob/master/src/label_image.py) and you can change the file locations as per your need.

Note: If graph file is not created you may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267743/tensorflow-retrain-py-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory/44685809#44685809) regarding running retrain.py